# Logging out Windows 7 users remotely?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, remote-desktop

Would it be possible from a remote computer log out a user sitting on a specific computer?

That is, can I a Administrator of a small network with some PC:s running Windows 7, log out a certain user on that LAN on a specific PC from another PC which is not even on the same LAN?

Sometimes I am working out of office, but would like to be able to log out users which is currently logged in to computers on our office LAN.

I have seen a lot of questions regarding how to log out users that has logged in to my own computer via remote desktop, but I want to be able to do the other way around.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are using a VPN or other tunnel to connect to your lan?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do if you don't mind rebooting the machine is to issue a `shutdown -r -t 0` via [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx):

`psexec \\{computer-name} -u Administrator -p {administrator-password} C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 0`

I think this may work to logout the currently logged in user but have not tried it:

`psexec \\{computer-name} -u Administrator -p {administrator-password} C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe -l -t 0`